# Integral inequality $\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}x^x\operatorname{W(x)}\operatorname{dx}<\frac{1}{9c-15}$

Tags: integration, inequality, closed-form, alternative-proof, lambert-w

Hi It's a problem create by me :

> > $$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}x^x\operatorname{W(x)}\operatorname{dx}<\frac{1}{9c-15}≈0.193990261767$$
> >     Where $c$ is the [Takeuchi-Prellberg Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Takeuchi-PrellbergConstant.html)

I think it's interesting to have the Lambert's function in the expression of the Takeuchi-Prellberg Constant, in the asymptotic  behavior of the [Bell's numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BellNumber.html) and in the integral .Furthermore as we know $x^x=z$ have as solution $x=\exp(\operatorname{W(ln(z))})$

### What I have tried so far :

I use power series of $f(x)=x^x$ at $x=1$ we have :

$$f(x)=1 + (x - 1) + (x - 1)^2 + 1/2 (x - 1)^3 + 1/3 (x - 1)^4 + 1/12 (x - 1)^5 + 3/40 (x - 1)^6 - 1/120 (x - 1)^7 + (59 (x - 1)^8)/2520 +O((x - 1)^9)
$$

And :

$$g(x)=\operatorname{W_0(x)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-n)^{n-1}}{n!}x^n$$

Remains to multiply the two  troncated series and integrate to get the desired result

### My question :

Can someone improve the upper bound or give a closed form ?

Thanks a lot for your time and patience

Comment: What are you doing in Besançon ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developing the integrand as a series around $x=1$, we have
$$x^x\,W(x)=w+\frac{w (w+2)}{(w+1)}(x-1)+\frac{w (w+2) (2 w^2+3w+2) }{2 (w+1)^3}(x-1)^2+\frac{w \left(w^2+3 w+3\right) \left(3 w^3+11 w^2+8 w+3\right)}{6 (w+1)^5}(x-1)^3+\frac{w \left(8 w^7+58 w^6+180 w^5+321 w^4+368 w^3+276 w^2+104 w+20\right) }{24 (w+1)^7 }(x-1)^4+O\left((x-1)^5\right)$$ where $w=W(1)=\Omega$.

As a function of $n$ the dgeree of expansion, we then have for the integral a closed form
$$I_n= \frac{w \,P_{2n-1}(w)}{2^{n+1}\, (n+1)!\,(1+w)^{2n-1}}$$
 the numerical results are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \text{value} \\
 0 & 0.283571645204892 \\
 1 & 0.167441701824308 \\
 2 & 0.201682086153625 \\
 3 & 0.192560070537807 \\
 4 & 0.194346190147895 \\
 5 & 0.193957003195521 \\
 6 & 0.194004358724321 \\
 7 & 0.193991317451300 \\
 8 & 0.193991160551488 \\
 9 & 0.193990511889642 \\
 10 & 0.193990358194065 \\
 11 & 0.193990294268921 \\
 12 & 0.193990272085633 \\
 13 & 0.193990263830734 \\
 14 & 0.193990260767764 \\
 15 & 0.193990259611595 \\
 16 & 0.193990259170115 \\
 17 & 0.193990258999433 \\
 18 & 0.193990258932675 \\
 19 & 0.193990258906272 \\
 20 & 0.193990258895718 \\
\cdots &   \cdots   \\
\infty &0.193990258888496
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

For the fun of it (this comes from a friend of mine) an upper bound of the ntegral is 
$$\frac{-2+2 \sqrt{3}-3 e+6 \pi -2 \pi ^2+7 \log (2)}{5+11 \sqrt{2}+2 \sqrt{3}-3
   e-\pi -2 \pi ^2-7 \log (2)-2 \log (3)}$$ for a relative error of $1.44\times 10^{-17}$%.
 Looking more serious is (from the inverse symbolic calculator)
$$\frac{\sqrt[4]{3} \left(16-\sqrt[3]{2}\right)}{100} $$
It also looks very similar to the smallest root of$$1928 x^2-4833 x+865=0\implies x=\frac{4833-\sqrt{16687009}}{3856}$$

Comment: I don't believe it .I was thinking it was much harder  .Cool (+1).Merci.

Comment: @The.old.boy. You are very welcome ! When I saw your post yesterday evening, being in love with Lambert (function), I have been quite excited and started this morning at 4:00am ! The problem is that the formulae of the $P_{2n-1}(w)$ are really messy and it takes a long time to compute the exact value of the $I_n$ as soon as $n>10$. I just noticed that you are in Besançon. I am in Pau.